# Power Query transform custom column into T/F statement

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have an Excel report that returns a column with worker's province changes over time coded like the following:
`SK36 > SK30 > AB01` where only the first 2 letters matter (province codes) and the 2 numbers after the letters don't matter. there can be up to 10 codes in the same cell like: `ON## > ON## > BC## > BC## > BC##....`

what I'm looking for is a query that would return "True" if there is at least 1 instance of a different province, and "False" if they are all the same provinces:

`AB01 > AB55 > AB75` = `True`

`SK36 > SK30 > AB01`=`False`

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what were the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this custom column will do the work:

```
if List.Count(
    List.Distinct(
        List.Transform(
            Text.Split([YourColumnName], " > "), 
            each Text.Start(_,2)
        )
    )
) > 1 then "True" else "False"
```

Answer (score 4):

**PowerQuery**:

```
List.MatchesAll(
    Text.Split([Input]," > "), (n)=> Text.Start(n,2) = Text.Start([Input],2)
)
```

Or possibly better:

```
List.Count(
    List.Distinct(Text.Split(Text.Remove([Input],{"0".."9"})," > "))
)>1
```

---

Or if this reverses the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values, just change to:

```
List.MatchesAny(
    Text.Split([Input]," > "), (n)=> Text.Start(n,2) <> Text.Start([Input],2)
)
```

Or possibly better:

```
List.Count(
    List.Distinct(Text.Split(Text.Remove([Input],{"0".."9"})," > "))
)=1
```

---

**Formula**:

```
=MAP([Input],LAMBDA(n,SUM(N(LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(n," > "),2)<>LEFT(n,2)))>0))
```

Or, to reverse the logic again:

```
=MAP([Input],LAMBDA(n,SUM(N(LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(n," > "),2)<>LEFT(n,2)))=0))
```

Comment: Wow so many ways. At least 6 i can see. Cool tricks!!!